# The Office Quote: "You know, if we hung Holly from the ceiling..."

Tags: the-office

In the season 4 episode 18 (Goodbye Toby) of 'The Office', Michael says "You know, if we hung Holly from the ceiling, we'd have to kiss underneath of her."

I don't get this punchline. What does that mean? Is there any cultural reference here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What does that mean? Is there any cultural reference here?

### I suppose, yeah.

Michael's referring to the Christmas tradition of [hanging up mistletoe and kissing underneath it](https://www.history.com/news/why-do-we-kiss-under-the-mistletoe). But, instead, he mixes up mistletoe with holly; a reference to the Christmas carol, "Deck the Halls":

> **Deck the halls with boughs of holly**
> Fa la la la la, la la la la (fa la la la la, la la la la)
> 'Tis the season to be jolly
> Fa la la la la, la la la la (fa la la la la, la la la la)